# listview details not show data properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm displaying data inside listview as I'm suggested in previous quesiton but I'm having mistake.
Data should display like this

```
CODE | NAME | PRICE
--------------------
122a  myname  122.99
```

but I'm having this

```
CODE | NAME | PRICE
--------------------
      122a    myname
```

Code is following

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Code");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Name");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Price");

            foreach (MyData in dataList)
            {
                var row = new ListViewItem();
                row.SubItems.Add(a.Code);
                row.SubItems.Add(a.Name);
                row.SubItems.Add(a.Price.ToString("F"));

                listView1.Items.Add(row);

            }
            listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text for the first column should be added as the ItemText at ListViewItem constructor

```
foreach (MyData in dataList)
{
    var row = new ListViewItem(a.Code);
    row.SubItems.Add(a.Name);
    row.SubItems.Add(a.Price.ToString("F"));
    listView1.Items.Add(row);
}
```

You could check the example on the [ListViewItem.SubItems topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx)